# Jews in Mitzrayim

Tags: passover

Where were the Jews Sprirtually holding during the 210 years in Egypt . How we balance they kept their jewish names /language/clothing verses gd had to redeem them or they wouldn't be redeemed?

Comment: You are asking that based on the fact that they were keeping their names, language, and way of dress, how could it be that they were on such a low level?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question is not simple or straightforward. In fact, there seems to be a contradiction between two sources in the Tanakh that describe the spiritual state of the Jews in Mitzrayim. In Shemos (Exodus) 4:29-31, we read that Moshe and Aharon gathered the elders of Israel and told them what God had said to Moshe at the burning bush. They also performed signs and wonders to prove their authenticity. The verse says: "And the people believed; and when they heard that the Lord had remembered the children of Israel, and that He had seen their affliction, then they bowed their heads and prostrated themselves." This implies that the Jews in Mitzrayim had faith in God and His promises, and that they accepted Moshe as their leader and redeemer.

However, in Yechazkel (Ezekiel) 20:5-8, we read a different account. God tells Yechazkel to remind the rebellious house of Israel of their history and their sins. He says: "And I said unto them: Cast ye away every man the detestable things of his eyes, and defile not yourselves with the idols of Egypt; I am the Lord your God. But they rebelled against Me, and would not hearken unto Me; they did not every man cast away the detestable things of their eyes, nor did they forsake the idols of Egypt." This implies that the Jews in Mitzrayim were idol worshipers and rebels against God, and that they did not listen to Moshe or follow his instructions.

How can we reconcile these two sources? How can we understand the spiritual condition of the Jews in Mitzrayim? There are several approaches that have been suggested by various commentators and scholars over the centuries. Here are some of them:

- According to the Midrash that the OP mentioned (Vayikra Rabbah 32:5), one of the merits that enabled the Jews to be redeemed from Mitzrayim was that they did not change their names or language (and according to some versions, also their clothing). This means that they preserved some aspects of their identity and culture as a distinct nation, even though they assimilated in other ways. The Abarbanel (Bereishis 15:14) suggests that this was a result of a mixed attitude towards idolatry among the Jews. He says that some of them believed in both God and idols, while others rejected idolatry completely. He explains that those who believed in both God and idols had a sense of pride and dignity as the children of Abraham, and therefore kept their names and language as a sign of their heritage. However, those who rejected idolatry completely were more humble and modest, and therefore changed their names and language to avoid drawing attention to themselves or provoking hostility from their oppressors.
- The Ran (Bereishis 15:14) and Eliyahu Rabbah (21) say that the Jews in Mitzrayim were completely monotheistic and never served idols. They explain that Yechazkel 20:5-8 refers only to a minority of Jews who were influenced by the Egyptian culture and worshiped idols. However, the majority of Jews remained faithful to God and His covenant. They say that this is why Moshe was able to gather them all together and convince them to follow him out of Mitzrayim.

Based on these approaches, we can understand how different opinions may view the balance between the urgency and necessity of the redemption from Mitzrayim. According to those who say that the Jews only did not change their language or name (and maybe clothing), they were on the cusp of losing their identity and faith completely. Therefore, God had to intervene at that exact moment to save them from total assimilation and destruction. However, according to those who say that the Jews were monotheistic and loyal to God, they were not in such a dire situation. Therefore, God could have waited longer or chosen a different time or method for their redemption.

https://alhatorah.org/Religious_Identity_in_Egypt/2 Brings many more sources and opinions

Answer (score 0):

The Jews (with the exception of the Levites) were literally serving idols and fully mired in Egyptian sin, as related in the Haggadah.
There were those three differences of custom, and they had heard that they would be redeemed, but were essentially spiritually equivalent to Egyptian hedonists. They kept custom out of habit and not out of profound religious meditation. If they had all decided to stay Egyptian, it wouldn't matter how they dressed; they would not have been redeemed because they wouldn't have even wanted it. I hope that addresses the question sufficiently, but if not please expand.

(Significantly though, the sefer מנהג ישראל תורה relates in the introduction that this shows how important Jewish customs are. If we were idol worshippers and were redeemed just for these customs, that demonstrates that keeping even small customs like these can save the Jewish nation. We shouldn't make light of abandoning our Jewish names, language, or dress.

Likewise, the author relates how Jewish communities withstood forceful efforts to convert or assimilate Jews for hundreds of years that were largely unsuccessful, until the reform movement  came around and started to attempt to make changes to Jewish custom instead of law, a new kind of attack with devastating results. Historically, that period then saw entire communities fall to assimilation and intermarriage.

Further, he points out that anti-judaic philosophers and debaters were historically only ever really successful against those who considered themselves knowledgeable enough to debate Jewish custom; the majority unlearned population, and virtually all Jewish women, never fell prey to such attempts.)